# android-switch-backport -- how do you set resources?

Tags: android

How do you set resources such as textOff?

I started with the example [android-switch-backport-master/sample](https://github.com/BoD/android-switch-backport) and modified **res/layout/main.xml** like so:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:switch="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.sample"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOff="test"
        switch:asb_switchTextOff="@string/foo"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Note the additions of `xmlns:switch="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.sample"`
 and `switch:asb_switchTextOff="@string/foo"`. (@string/foo is defined elsewhere).

The compiler seems happy, however the "off" state of the switch still says "Off". Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Or should I forget this backport completely and use the v7 compatibility library?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out. Posting here for others who have the same question:

The resource is `asb_textOff`, not `asb_switchTextOff`. The latter is for switchpreferences.

```
<org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOff="test"
    switch:asb_textOff="@string/foo"
    />
```